# Calculating the gain of a transistor in VGA

Tags: transistors, gain, small-signal, automatic-gain-control

This paper is from IEEE:

[image: circuit]

The gain of the first VGA is expressed as \$  A_1 = \frac{gm_1 R_1}{1+gm_1 R_2+\frac{R_2}{ro_1}} \$

However, I thought that since the (DC) current source at the source of M1 is considered open in small signal (AC) analysis, the gain would be: \$  A_1 = \frac{gm_1 R_1}{ro_1+ro_2} \$ 
The second calculation is however, more confusing:

[image: vga gain]

it shows that \$  A_2 = \frac{gm_3 \times (R_4 // R_5)}{1+ \frac{gm_3 R_3}{2} + \frac{R_3}{2 ro_3}} \$

I would get that if R4 was \$ro_4\$ and the divisor was \$ ro_3 \$ but I really don't understand this. It is clearly true, because it is published by IEEE. Could you walk me through how the gain(s) is calculated?

Comment: *However, I thought that since the current source at the source of M1 is considered shorted in AC analysis* I do not follow you there, the two current sources cannot be shorted. The M2 transistors are still present between the sources. Changing the Rds of these transistors is the basis of the VGA. It is similar to source resistors in a differential pair.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie you are right, infact they are DC current sources so they should be ignred (open circuit) in small signall analysis. I'll edit the question.